# Apple TV ungroups songs in an album

Tags: itunes, appletv, itunes-match

I'm seeing this issue all too frequently with some albums on my Apple TV. When I try to search for an album, the tracks are not grouped within one album. Instead, the Apple TV creates duplicate list items (different tracks though) resulting in not being able to play the album all at once.

The weird thing is that they group fine into one album within iTunes itself. One of the albums displayed in my screenshots below was even bought on iTunes.

Any help on how to get it neatly grouped into one album?

P.S.: Already restarted the Apple TV and logged in and out. Using iTunes Match

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]
[image: Example 3]
[image: Example 4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same here. I found a easy 2 step approach to solve the problem.

1.) Make sure you have ticked the compilation box in iTunes and delete the album artists completely.

2.) After your Apple TV updated the music library the compilation will be together as one (with "Verschiedene Interpreten" in German, wich is "Various Artists" in English). After that you can re-enter any Album Artist you want, the ATV will not split up the Album again.

Comment: you're a hero man

Answer (score 0):

This is the result of songs in the album having different artists. It's a common problem, but thankfully easy to fix.

#### Different artists in one album? How is this possible?

Generally, albums that have multiple artists are [compilation albums](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compilation_album). Meaning that not every artist that contributed to the album, contributed to every song.

If this isn't the case, the file info may be incorrect.

#### How do I fix it?

You can change each song's artist to match all of the others.

1. Right click on the album in iTunes.
2. Select "Get Info".
3. Accept the prompt by clicking "Edit Items".
4. Find the "Artist" field.
5. Change it to whatever you like.

Comment: Change it to whatever you like? But that's horrible if you have a nicely organised library. Album artist is filled in as Various Artists. Shouldn't that group it automatically like it does in iTunes.

Comment: "Whatever you like" should more accurately be "the correct artist", but you could potentially change it to *literally* whatever you like. Also, when sorting by artist, it sorts by the "Artist" field; not the "Album Artist" field. @Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: but all the different artists are already filled into the artist field since I bought this from iTunes. There's no info missing and other albums that I formatted the same way and are also compilations don't do this (look at Hotel Costes 8 in the screenshot)

Comment: Correct. No info is missing. However, lets say the first song is by "John Doe", the second song is by "John Doe & Jane Doe", and the third song is by "John Doe & Friends". Each song has a different artist, even though they all have the same "Album" field info. Your reference to Hotel Costes 8 has no connection, because every song in that album may have the same "Artist" field info; regardless of the "Album Artist" info. It's confusing, I know. @Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: Yeah but that's why Album Artist is filled in as Various Artists. That way it groups into one album and iTunes acts like if I were to fill in the same artist for every track. Besides the info would just be incorrect if I changed it to eg. John Doe everywhere

Comment: The info would be incorrect, which is unfortunate, but there's sadly nothing else you can do to fix it (except live with it). Maybe you would like to [suggest a fix for this to Apple](http://www.apple.com/feedback/). @Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: but it's only occurring on 20% of my compilation albums. The other 80% is formatted the same way and works grouped into one album (this is why the Album Artist field exists in the first place). There's really no need to enter incorrect info, I think im either missing a field or this is a bug on the Apple tv.

Comment: Could you take a quick screenshot of the info for Hôtel Costes 8? @Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: it's exactly the same just with a different album title

Comment: Is every song separated into its own album? Or are there a few in clumps? @Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: in iTunes every album I have is correctly grouped so no seperate/duplicate albums. On the Apple tv they're seperated but some are grouped per 3 or per 2

Comment: Then the problem is just as I have said. These clumps of 2 or 3 all have the same "Artist" field info, but are different from the other clumps, but ALL of the songs have the same "Album". That's why it appears as multiple manifestations of the same album. I would recommend [leaving Apple some feedback](http://www.apple.com/feedback/). There's not much else I can do to help. :( **Note:** The "Album Artist" does not affect anything while sorting.@Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: but then why does it work in iTunes and why are the Album Artist and tickbox for compilation there? Surely this must be some bug for Apple Tv's iOS

Comment: It may be an oversight in sorting, definitely an inconvenience, but almost certainly not a bug. Perhaps you could try a different type of sorting. @Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: Well that's really messed up. That way Apple forces me in giving incorrect information and added 2 useless input fields just taking up space…

Comment: Sorry, man. I know how you feel. I'm very OCD about my songs and song info. Try thinking about it as omission rather than incorrect. Good luck! @Thibmaekelbergh

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27038/discussion-between-thibmaekelbergh-and-zach-gates).